# Custom nanddump and nandwrite tools

Tags: firmware, dumping, memory-dump

I am trying to reverse engineer a router's firmware. The device has a NAND chip, and has a cripled version of BusyBox v1.14.1. `nanddump` command exists but with intresting parameters, as I wasn't able to find any info on Google. Also `nandwrite` command doesn't exist, instead they wrote a different tool called `psi` to write to the chip. Here are the outputs of their usage with compare to the original counterparts.

```
$ nanddump
Usage: nanddump mtdX [noswap || swap] [nospare || spare] sector_count
        sector_count can be provided as "0" which means the whole partition
```

So, what are these swap and spare options for? When I try to dump with `swap`or `noswap` I got the same file when I use the command `cat /dev/mtd* > mtd*.bin`. However using `spare` parameter gives a slightly bigger file. Here is what I got from full fledged busybox

```
$ nanddump
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2013-07-08 10:56:01 CDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: nanddump [-o] [-b] [-s ADDR] [-f FILE] MTD_DEVICE

Dump the specified MTD device

        -o      Dump oob data
        -b      Omit bad block from the dump
        -s ADDR Start address
        -l LEN  Length
        -f FILE Dump to file ('-' for stdout)
```

And for the other tool, `psi`

```
$ psi
usage: psi -o <command> -t <configtype> -f <filename|env.var.name> -s <flashsize> -r <rebootflag>
supported commands: <read> <write> <erase>
supported config types: <asd> <cfg> <env> <flash> <firmware>
supported reboot flags: <yes> <no>
Note: -s parameter is for flash dump/undump only
```

It seems like this tool reads and writes at the same time. Well this is hard to figure out as I wasn't able to use it to read mtd partitions, and it doesn't let firmware partition to be read. It only writes to that partition. Here is the `nandwrite` command from busybox.

```
$ nandwrite
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2013-07-08 10:56:01 CDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: nandwrite [-p] [-s ADDR] MTD_DEVICE [FILE]

Write to the specified MTD device

        -p      Pad to page size
        -s ADDR Start address
```

So I believe `flashsize` from `psi`command has something to do with these two parameters. 
Also here is the list of `mtd`

```
$ cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 01000000 00004000 "RootFS"
mtd1: 08000000 00020000 "FlashAll"
mtd2: 00020000 00020000 "Bootloader"
mtd3: 00220000 00020000 "BootloaderConfig"
mtd4: 00220000 00020000 "Config"
mtd5: 00220000 00020000 "ASD"
mtd6: 02200000 00020000 "Kernel"
mtd7: 02200000 00020000 "KernelBackup"
mtd8: 02e60000 00020000 "disk"
mtd9: 00220000 00020000 "edr"
mtd10: 00500000 00020000 "bbt"
```

Custom `nanddump` throws an error while reading `RootFS`. These are all I got for now.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t know what swap is about, but *spare* area, or OOB area is an additional area at the end of each page storing metadata such as:

- bad block markers
- ECC (error checking and correcting) code
- custom data which may be used by the system

It seems the `spare` option enables dumping it which is why the dump is slightly bigger.

For more info about NAND flash organization see [this nice document](https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/nandflash.pdf) from Lauterbach

Comment: thank you for your response. i checked that document it is indeed a nice one. as you said i confirmed that ```spare``` option is for extra data from the chips [datasheet](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/6851/MX30LF1G08AA,%203V,%201Gb,%20v1.5.pdf). Also i have realized that swap changes endiannes of the dumps. I have bootloader dump which has "cfe" written in normal one and when swapped it becomes "efc". I also was able to dump using ```psi``` command. It's dumping as multiples of 64KB data. I believe that is page size, but I am not sure. ```psi``` command has no ecc option